# ForEach-Object -Parallel within foreach returning different result

Tags: powershell, foreach

Dears,

follwoing code, returs different/random(?) results.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thank you!

```
$contacts = 200001..200064
while(1){
    $result = @{CSV=@()};
    foreach($contact in $contacts){
        $contacts | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
            ($using:result).CSV += "$($using:contact);$_"
        } -ThrottleLimit 30
    }
    $result.CSV.Count
}
```

Expected count = 4096
Returns:
4095
4092
4095
4096
4095
4096
4096
4096
4094
4092
...

Going to `-ThrottleLimit 1` seems to "solve" it, however I am losing the advantage of Parallel

Using following PS (core) version:

```
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: "Does anyone have an idea why?" - the really simple answer is "because your code isn't thread-safe". This particularly - ```($using:result).CSV += "$($using:contact);$_"``` has a race condition where two threads can simultaneously assign their new value to the ```CSV``` member and one overwrites the other's change, effectively losing it. Use a thread-safe type like ```ConcurrentBag``` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-7.0) or any of the other thread-safe types in the base class library...

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.
$cbResult = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[object]]::new();
($using:cbResult).TryAdd("$($using:contact);$_") | Out-Null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are not inherintly thread-safe, so doing multiple `$array += ...` operations concurrently might result in race conditions where two updates overlap, hence the missing items in the final array.

Use a thread-safe collection type instead, like a `ConcurrentQueue` for example:

```
$contacts = 200001..200064
while(1){
    $result = @{CSV=[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[psobject]]::new()};
    foreach($contact in $contacts){
        $contacts | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
            [void]($using:result).CSV.TryAdd("$($using:contact);$_")
        } -ThrottleLimit 30
    }
    $result.CSV.Count
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77127124/15339544) explains the thread safety issue with your current code and provides a way to solve it by using a thread safe type that allows adding to it from multiple threads but there is a much easier way to do it in this case, and that is by simply outputting from your parallel loop and capturing that output in your current thread. Depending on your need, this might be not only simpler but also more efficient.

```
$contacts = 200001..200064
while (1) {
    $result = foreach ($contact in $contacts) {
        $contacts | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
            "$($using:contact);$_"
        } -ThrottleLimit 30
    }
    $result = @{ Csv = $result }
    $result.CSV.Count
}
```